# How to make an array of matrices in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that reads a couple of lists as inputs, 1 tells you if resistance is in series or parallel string form, the other contains values of resistances for each component, and outputs an array containing a set of matrices. If the resistance is series, the matrix is of the form 
`([1 R],[0 1])`.
If the resistance is parallel, the matrix is of the form `([1 0], [1/R 1])`.
The idea is at the end of this ill have an array or data frame where each element is a matrix, and then ill multiply all matrices together.
I've tried coding it to no avail.
Are there any ways I can make this in python?

Kind regards,

Tom_Ice

Comment: please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

In general, would be good to post your tries. Anyway if I understood the problem you want something like this:

```
def to_matrix(labels, r_values):

matrices = []

for label, R in zip(labels, r_values):
    if label == 'series':
        matrices.append(np.array([[1, float(R)], [0, 1]]))
    elif label == 'parallel':
        matrices.append(np.array([[1, 0], [1/float(R), 1]]))

 return matrices



if __name__ == "__main__":

    labels = ['parallel', 'series', 'parallel']
    values = [10, 100, 1000]
    matrices = to_matrix(labels, values)
```

You initialize an array where to put matrices, then you iterate the received list appending the matrix and at the end, you have a list of matrices. In order to make it work you have to install numpy. The multiplication would be easier with the function

```
np.matmul(matrix1, matrix2)
```

So, if you need a multiplication of all list's elements you could do something like this:

```
result = matrices[0]
for m in matrices[1:]:
    result = np.matmul(result, m)


print(*result, sep=('\n'))
```